# CONTINUE WHEN example explanation - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, continue

Hi there I'm trying to interpret the result of the following examples but I could not figure out why. Hope someone could shed a light on it for me. Thank you

[Code + Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpdrd.png)

```
DECLARE 
 v_total NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
 <<BeforeTopLoop>>
 FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
   v_total := v_total + 1;
   dbms_output.put_line('Total is: ' || v_total);
   FOR j IN 1..10 LOOP
     CONTINUE BeforeTopLoop WHEN i + j > 5;
     v_total := v_total + 1;
   END LOOP;
 END LOOP;
END two_loop;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Also, please don’t link to images. Provide all the relevant information directly in your question, preferably as editable text

Comment: My question is how these 2 loops work that give the results in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<<BeforeTopLoop>>` is a label that can be the target of certain flow control operations, like `CONTINUE`.

In the example below, it just shortcuts the inner loop conditionally and transfers control to the top of the outer loop, while keeping the current state of variables.

To expose the state changes of `total`, see the following suggestion.

Try adjusting the procedure in the following way, then rerun.

You'll notice how the total is incremented by the inner loop without hitting the outer put_line statement.

```sql
DECLARE 
 v_total NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
 <<BeforeTopLoop>>
 FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
   v_total := v_total + 1;
   dbms_output.put_line('Total is: ' || v_total);
   FOR j IN 1..10 LOOP
     CONTINUE BeforeTopLoop WHEN i + j > 5;
     v_total := v_total + 1;
     dbms_output.put_line('Intermediate is: ' || v_total);   -- Try adding this line and run again
   END LOOP;
 END LOOP;
END two_loop;
```

The result:

```
Total is: 1
Intermediate is: 2
Intermediate is: 3
Intermediate is: 4
Intermediate is: 5
Total is: 6
Intermediate is: 7
Intermediate is: 8
Intermediate is: 9
Total is: 10
Intermediate is: 11
Intermediate is: 12
Total is: 13
Intermediate is: 14
Total is: 15
Total is: 16
Total is: 17
Total is: 18
Total is: 19
Total is: 20
```

Comment: Thank you. Turned out I didn't know that when the flow goes back to the inner loop, j restarts to 1.  But I have a follow up Q, what is "END two_loop;" ? in the code we did not really name any block "two_loop" tho?

Comment: @tuoni It's an optional name you can provide to indicate the block to which the `END` applies.  Oracle says: _The name of the block to which END applies — a label, function name, procedure name, or package name._